# library twitteR issues when reading an external file

Tags: r, file, twitter

I have no internet connection and I just want to make a program using the library twitteR of R. For that purpose I have downloaded the file rdmTweets.RData that it is supposed to hold a collection of twitters. That file is available in: http://www.rdatamining.com/data

I have try to read that file using:

```
  rdmTweets<-userTimeline("rdmTweets.RData",n=200)
```

also converting directly to a data frame:

```
  df<-do.call("rbind",lapply("rdmTweets.RData",as.data.frame)
```

but, with no results at all. I mean it does not show any information of the twitters. I tried to read it like a file with:

```
  rdm<-file("rdmTweets.RData","r")
  lines<-readLines(rdm)
```

also with no results. It seems the only way that I can access that file is when I have:

```
  rdmTweets<-userTimeline("rdatamining",n=200)
```

but that means to have an active internet connection. So the question that I have is how I can read that file in a way that I can get its contents like if I use userTimeline?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To read a RData file, you need to use *load()*.

Run the code below. The 1st line loads a data object *rdmTweets* from file, and the 2nd converts it into a data frame. You also need to have package twitteR installed.

```
load("rdmTweets.RData")
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(rdmTweets, as.data.frame))
```